# Atualizar planilha fechada com VBA

Tags: python, vba, excel-vba

Comunidade, bom dia!

Sou iniciante em VBA e Python e queria tirar uma dúvida que não encontrei na internet nem nas questões aqui:

Fiz um programa em VBA e gostaria que a planilha se atualizasse todos os dias sem que eu precise abrí-la.
Há alguma forma de programar isso com o VBA? Se não, seria com Python mesmo? Ou há alguma solução mais objetiva?

Muito obrigado desde já!

Comment: Podes criar uma tarefa agendada no windows, que abra o ficheiro excel. no excel, crias load event que execute as tuas macros, e no final salvas e fechas o excel

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, espero que ajude, é só substituir os nomes das pastas e o diretório do arquivo. Se precisar de ajuda é só falar.

```
Private Sub NºCI_Click()
```

Dim FolderName As String, wbName As String, cValue As Variant

```
Dim wbList As String, sValuePlan1 As String
```

'Path (Diretorio) -Ajustar o Caminho

```
    FolderName = "H:\user\my user\Pastas pessoais\sua pasta\pasta do arquivo"
```

'Nome do Arquivo de onde extrairemos a informação

```
        wbName = ("nome do arquivo com o formato correto")
```

'Armazenamos nas Variaveis

```
            wbList = wbName
            wbName = CI
```

'le o Valor no workbook

```
                cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList, "Nome da Sheet", "célula que vc quer")
```

'Msgbox com o Valor em A1

```
               Range("J8") = cValue
```

'Armazenamos o Valor na variavel

```
                    sValuePlan1 = cValue
```

'Coloca o Valor na Celula da planilha atual em que vc esta trabalhando

```
                        Cells(10, 8).Formula = cValue
```

End Sub

'Declaração da variavel

Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, _

```
wbName As String, _ wsName As String, _
cellRef As String) As Variant
    Dim arg As String
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ""
        If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
        If Dir(wbPath & "\" & wbName) = "" Then Exit Function
            arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
            wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
                On Error Resume Next
                    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
```

End Function